# Android DES algorithm default attributes

Tags: java, android, encryption, des

I am using following code for encryption in Android project:

```
SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
String key = "abcdefg";
DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
SecretKey _key = kf.generateSecret(keySpec);
String xform = "DES";
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(xform);
byte[] IV = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 18, 69, 17, 72, 94, 18, 30 };
IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, _key, ips);
String plainText = "abcdeffdkflsdkf";
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
```

I write this encrypted data in file and I want to decrypt this file in my java project where I am using following code:

```
SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
String key = "abcdefg";
DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
SecretKey _key = kf.generateSecret(keySpec);
String xform = "DES";
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(xform);
byte[] IV = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 18, 69, 17, 72, 94, 18, 30 };
IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, _key, ips);
String cipherText;
//cipher text is read from file.
byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText.getBytes());
```

But it's not working.
When we do not specify mode of operation(i.e. `CBC/ECB`) and padding method(i.e. `PKCS5Padding/NoPadding`) and only algorithm name is specified for getting instance of Cipher then what are the default values which Android and Java use?

Does Android uses CBC by default? As it doesn't give error for IV. If I specify IV in `init` method and don't specify mode in my java project, it throws exception as IV cannot be used for ECB.

Thanks.

Comment: DES is the mode which Android has as default..k can you able to get the same text after decryption and encryption process completed ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Why would you not just specify the mode and padding? It's reasonable that it'd throw an exception if you tried to use an IV with ECB. DES is very weak, is there a reason you're not using AES?

Comment: the line `String cipherText` suggest you are trying to store the output of encryption in a String. You can't without going through an additional layer of encoding like Base64, and it is probably unnecessary.

Comment: I want to know default operation mode and padding which Android uses when only algorithm name is specified e.g. "DES". I am not storing output of encryption in a String, it's a byte array.

Comment: It would be nice if you would accept some answers, gauri.

Answer (score 0):

Both Android and Java default to `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`. Both your key and IV are not of the correct size (so the code should not even run!) and you forget to perform (character) encoding/decoding correctly. Especially the ciphertext should never be directly converted into a string, as unprintable characters are likely to be dropped or converted.